# Sending a redirect

Tags: force.com, visualforce, redirect

I have a hyperlink in an email which will open an opportunity using the standard opportunity page. Before the opportunity page is open I want to carry out some business logic.  I only want this business logic to be executed when the hyperlink is clicked in the email. If someone hits the opportunity any other way without hitting URL in the email, I do not want this particular business logic to execute.

My intended approach to do this is send the URL in the email to another page, carry out the business logic in a back end controller and then return a redirect to the opportunity page.

I want to use this approach as I was don't want a custom controller for the opportunity. I want to leave that all alone.

Is it possible to do redirects in force.com?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new page, lets say `FirstPage` and add it to your URL. In that page use the `action` attribute of the `apex:page`, do your logic and then redirect the user to the opportunity page:

The page:

```
<apex:page controller="RedirectController" action="{!redirectToPage}">
    PLease wait...
</apex:page>
```

Extention controller:

```
public with sharing class RedirectController {

    private Id id;

    public RedirectController() {
        // Getting the id of the current record
        this.id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('opid');
    }

    // Here do your logic and then redirect user to the opportunity page
    public PageReference redirectToPage() {
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + this.id);
        return page;
    }
}
```

In your Email link use the new page and transfer opportunity-ID as URL parameter:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/FirstPage&opid={!opportunityId}">Click me</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Note that this solution fails on pages shown in Salesforce Communities (due to the absolute URL used).  See [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/16097/450) for details, and an improved RedirectController that works with Communities.